# Can't retrieve Session Cookies using CookieManager of InAppwebview

Tags: flutter, dart, session-cookies, flutter-inappwebview, cookiemanager

I'm trying to get session Cookies of a Webview  using **InAppwebview and CoookieManager** widget in my flutter App, it works fine in Android and IOS simulator but doesn't in IOS  real device .

**Here is my trial**

IOS version : +11

**Options :**
sharedCookiesEnabled: true 
incognito: false

```
build(BuildContext context) {
  var cookieObj = CookieManager();
  cookieObj.ios = IOSCookieManager();
  InAppWebView(
          initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
              ios: IOSInAppWebViewOptions(sharedCookiesEnabled: true),
              crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                incognito: false,
              )),
          initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
            url: Uri.parse("https://example.com"),
          ),
          onUpdateVisitedHistory: (controller, url, androidIsReload) {},
          onWebViewCreated: (controller) {},
          onLoadStop: (controller, url) {
            debugPrint(url!.origin);
            cookieObj.ios.getAllCookies().then((list) {
              if (list.isNotEmpty) {
                var filteredList = list
                    .where((element) =>
                        element.domain == 'example.com' &&
                        element.isSessionOnly == true)
                    .toList();
                if (filteredList.isNotEmpty) {
                  for (var element in filteredList) {
                    debugPrint('${element.name} :   ${element.value}');
                  }
                }
              }
            });
          },
        );
}
```

It retrieves when I'm inside webview once at first time "when it has been set ", but across my app. during navigation , I tried to cache it then , set it manually to the domain, not found  as well.

I'm stuck at this for. while , so any help , thanks n advanced